# Cloud Code for Parse.com, Query about Parse.User

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I need to write a background job in Cloud Code. 
It should query the 'User' class for each user, get the array of skills in the "offer" column. Then it should query the 'User' class again for each user comparing the skills from the first user on a match with all the other users.

Here is what I currently have..

```
Parse.Cloud.job("backgroundJob", function(request, status) {
// Set up to modify user data
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var counter = 0;
// Query for all users
var users_query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

users_query.find(function(user) {


               for(var i = 0; i < user.length; i++){
               var searchSkills = user[i].get("search");


               var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
               query.containedIn("offer", searchSkills);

               var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
               pushQuery.matchesQuery('user', query);

               }

               Parse.Push.send({
                               where: pushQuery,
                               data: {
                               alert: "Found someone close to you!"
                               }
                               }, {
                               success: function() {
                               // Push was successful
                               },
                               error: function(error) {
                               // Handle error
                               }
                               });


               status.message(counter + " users processed.");
               counter++;
               }).then(function() {
                       // Set the job's success status
                       status.success("Success");
                         }, function(error) {
                       // Set the job's error status
                       status.error("Error has been encountered");
                       });
            });
```

I get following error in the Push Notification saying: 
Cannot perform operation on non-existing column "offer"

Apparently it creates a new empty 'User' Class for my second user query. 
Any help would be very much appreciated.

UPDATE! Thats how my user class looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link for the containedIn method: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_containedIn

So you need to have an "offer" column on your user, that contains a value that would be found in the array searchSkills.  Sounds like you don't have an "offer" column. Maybe you have "Offer"? These are case sensitive.

For the second part, do you have a "user" field on your installations? That's something you'd have to set manually, I believe.  So it sounds like you never set that, and it's creating a blank user field for the query.

Also, Query.find can only return 1000 results. If you want to go through all of your users, you'll have to use Query.each instead.

Comment: My User class has an "offer" column, which contains an array of skills. These should be checked with the skills in the array searchSkills for a match. Tried both cases and it still didn't work.

Even if I leave out the two lines for installation query, it still does not work. Also don't I quit get what I have to do with manually adding a user to installation.. 

Thanks for the tip with Query.each

Comment: I'm not sure that Installation has a "user" field by default, so attaching the user to the installation is something you have to do manually on the client side.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help.